# "flatten" a list of maps to a single map in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to go from this list of maps, returned by a jdbc query:

```clj
'({:series_id 1 :expires_at "t1"} {:series_id 2 :expires_at "t2"})
```

to a single map like:

```clj
{1 "t1" 2 "t2"}
```

That's so I can look up `expires_at` using simply the `series_id` integer.

I've got as far as:

```clj
db.core=> (mapcat #((comp vals select-keys) %1 [:series_id :expires_at]) 
                  '({:series_id 1, :expires_at "t1"} {:series_id 2 :expires_at "t2"}))
(1 "t1" 2 "t2")
```

but that's a list, not a map.

I wonder if this is a candidate for reduce, and/or if there are some other neat ways to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert each map into a pair of `[series_id expires_at]` and then convert the corresponding sequences of pairs into a map:

```
(def l '({:series_id 1 :expires_at "t1"} {:series_id 2 :expires_at "t2"}))
(into {} (map (juxt :series_id :expires_at) l))
```

Comment: payoff of using clojure :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, with a list comprehension and destructuring

```
(defn flatten-expiration-data [the-maps]
 (into {}
  (for [{id :series_id expiration :expires_at} the-maps]
    [id expiration])))
```

It's more verbose than @Lee's answer, but I hope it also helps readers learn the language!